# Creating a Cloudwatch alarm on an existing Cloudwatch metric in CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, cloudwatch-alarms, aws-cdk-typescript

The API Gateway in AWS creates the metrics 4XXError and 5XXError for different APIs in CloudWatch. I need to set alarms for these already existing metrics in CDK.

I cannot find how you can import pre-existing CloudWatch metrics in CDK. Can anyone help me with how the code block would look for it?

Currently, the code looks like this

```
const externalPaymentFailedAlarm = new Alarm(
      this,
      `ExternalPaymentFailedAlarm`,
      {
        alarmDescription: `Alarm if external payment failed`,
        metric: new Metric({
          namespace: "v1/events",
          statistic: "SampleCount",
          metricName: "PUBLISH_SUCCESS",
          period: Duration.minutes(1),
          dimensionsMap: {
            EventName: "external_payment_failed",
            ServiceName: `${stage}-payment-failed`,
            LogGroup: `${stage}-payment-failed`,
            ServiceType: "AWS::Lambda::Function",
          },
          label: "External payment failed count",
        }),
        threshold: 1,
        evaluationPeriods: 1,
        datapointsToAlarm: 1,
      }
    );
    externalPaymentFailedAlarm.addAlarmAction(new SnsAction(alertsTopic));
```

Answer (score 2):

CloudWatch metrics are a very "ephemereal" entity in AWS, they don't exist outside of their datapoints.

So "importing" a metric is as simple as specifying its namespace, name, and dimensions, regardless if it already "exists" (i.e. there are datapoints with the same namespace, name, and dimensions) or not.

So what you're doing in the code block in the question is exactly what's required, as long as the parameters match the datapoints that the AWS service emits.

If your API is defined in CDK using the higher-level L2 constructs, you can use the provided abstractions instead. For example, [`HttpApi.metricServerError()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigatewayv2-alpha.HttpApi.html#metricwbrserverwbrerrorpropsspan-classapi-icon-api-icon-experimental-titlethis-api-element-is-experimental-it-may-change-without-noticespan) would give you a reference to the metric emitted by a specific API.

This is the preferred method of dealing with standard metrics in CDK.